# Easy Mock issue with Blob

Tags: easymock

We are using `Easy Mock` for creating `JUnit` test case in java with `H2` database.

As code of fetching the Blob content is specific to Oracle and getting the following error.

> ClassCastException: Cannot cast org.h2.jdbc.JdbcResultSet (id=72) to oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet

```
public BLOB getBLOB(String field) throws SQLException {
              try {return ((OracleResultSet) rs).getBLOB(field);
              } catch (NullPointerException e) {}}
```

Bit stuck with this as how can we handle this in `Easy Mock` without changing the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing something weird here. If you are using EasyMock to mock the blob, you should mock OracleResultSet, not JdbcResultSet.

You don't need H2 here. Since you are mocking.

As a side note: Please remote the empty catch of the NPE. You are heavily shooting yourself in the foot when doing that.

Comment: We are not mocking JdbcResultSet.In this case we are fetching the blob contents from database.empty catch

Comment: What is mocking then?

Answer (score 0):

We are not mocking JdbcResultSet.In this case we are fetching the blob contents from database so we can't mock OracleResultSet. Removed the code from Empty catch.